# Read file in FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

Before I get started, please know that I am completely new to FPGA stuffs. I was wondering if it is possible to store a file (*.txt or *.csv) in a FPGA and read it line by line (i.e. file I/O operations). Please let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

I'll be coding in VHDL and probably using the Xilinx XUPV5 LX110T board.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to initialize Block RAM with an external data file, but this file must be pure binary or hexadecimal content with no comments or other information. Then you can read and write in one cycle from different addresses. You can configure the RAM as dual-port. For more information check the XST User Guide for Virtex-5.
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/xst.pdf

Comment: The block of memory can contain values of type Character, if you need to process ASCII (sorry, LATIN-1) text. But if it contains numbers, pure binary is best. Either way I would recommend storing the data as a constant array in a VHDL package. It's easy to add the lines of VHDL you need around the actual values in a script, or even in a text editor.

Comment: XST supports a subset of textio for reading text files during synthesis. Unfortunately Vivado has regressed and can't do this yet.

Comment: Thank you! But, the contents of the file cannot be determined beforehand.  Also, the contents may change and are not constant. So, any suggestions?

Comment: You are welcome! You will have to implement a UART module into your FPGA in order to send data from the PC through RS-232 port to RAM.
There are ready to use UART IPs either for standalone use or bundled with some processor core (Picoblaze, Microblaze MCS, etc). You can even implement one yourself.
 
From Matlab you are going to use some serial object to communicate with the serial port of your PC.
Also you will have to test the maximum Baudrate the system can acheive.

Comment: P.S: A universal asynchronous receiver/transmitter,  is a piece of computer hardware that translates data between parallel and serial forms.

Comment: @Josh. Latin-1 is an 8-bit character set. If you really want to you can use textio to embed arbitrary binary data into an internal ROM. It isn't limited to just text.

Answer (score 1):

FPGA is not a micro controller, it does not have a file system or any other type of storage otions that some controller have.

But you can make the FPGA work like a controller by implementing a Soft CPU inside of it, like MicroBlaze or Neon. When you have that, you connect the CPU system to a SD card controller or connect via Uart or Ethernet to the place where your file is located, and read the file using the C code running on the SoftCore CPU.

Doing this in FPGA, for a person with no prior knowledge of how it works is going to be a very difficult task. You might be able to do this by creating a simple UART inside the FPGA and the have a state machine that receives the data from the UART and put it in the memory, but even that can be tricky and hard if you have never done this.

A third option is to convert the file into a binary and then convert that into a memory loadable file that you connect to a ROM or RAM inside the FPGA, but then, you have to recompile your project every time you want a new file!

There was a similar question on StackExchange some time ago:
[Transferring a 1MB bitstream to a FPGA and reading it out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29435/transferring-a-1mb-bitstream-to-a-fpga-and-reading-it-out)